# Is there combinational circuit design for a 6 operation ALU?

Tags: vhdl, alu

I'm trying to create a ALU in VHDL and I'm having a hard time implementing a couple of the operations. I've implemented the add, subtract, and and or operations but I'm wondering how I would implement the logical shift operations? The ALU is 32 bit but any design would be appreciated.

Comment: [so] is focussed on software issues - this is hardware design. Try asking on [electronics.se]

Comment: @MikeW - This could still be ok for SO, given it's about writing an implementation in VHDL.

Comment: @admdrew Possibly, but the OP is more likely to find someone with the relevant hardware design experience on [electronics.se]

Comment: @MikeW Agreed, and this question isn't very well written to begin with.

Comment: @MikeW - there's a reasonable number of VHDLers hanging out on SO as well as EE :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numeric_std` package contains logical shift operations, both `shift_right`
and `shift_left`:

```
function SHIFT_LEFT (ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED;
-- Result subtype: UNSIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0)
-- Result: Performs a shift-left on an UNSIGNED vector COUNT times.
--         The vacated positions are filled with '0'.
--         The COUNT leftmost elements are lost.

function SHIFT_RIGHT (ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED;
-- Result subtype: UNSIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0)
-- Result: Performs a shift-right on an UNSIGNED vector COUNT times.
--         The vacated positions are filled with '0'.
--         The COUNT rightmost elements are lost.
```

So based on this you can simply write code like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture syn of mdl is
  signal arg   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal count : std_logic_vector( 4 downto 0);
  signal res_r : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal res_l : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
  res_r <= std_logic_vector(shift_right(unsigned(arg), to_integer(unsigned(count))));
  res_l <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(arg), to_integer(unsigned(count))));
end architecture;
```

These operations are synthesizable, and maps nicely to FPGA resources if that
is your target device.

There has previously been some confusion around VHDL shift/rotate operators,
see [this
link](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/bit-shifts-in-vhdl.html),
but it has been cleaned up in VHDL-2008.  However, for backward compatibility
the above suggestion is based on functions instead of operators.